# ALTER TABLE not letting me set NULL or default value?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change an existing column in a table I have to allow for null values and then set the default value to null.  I tried running the following but it does not seem to be updating the table:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE answers_form MODIFY sub_id int unsigned NULL DEFAULT NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc answers_form;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| answer_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| sub_id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| form_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| value        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| non_response | bit(1)           | YES  |     | b'0'    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that you can't set this column to be nullable because it is part of the primary key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its a primary key , mysql doesn't allow any part of the primary key to be null, which does make the fact that it allows a default value of null for the form_id odd, however the docs at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html

say "*Query performance benefits from the NOT NULL optimization, because it cannot include any NULL values*".

Just out of curiosity, does it actually allow you to put in null values in the form_id field?

Comment: You could just do a little [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and find out for yourself.

Comment: I gave it a shot, and no I couldn't insert a null.  I'm guessing my best bet is to just use a unique key instead of a primary key in this case?

Comment: ok, atleast the behavior is consistant with the documentation, eventough the output of desc is misleading. And yes, a unique key, maybe even tastier, introduce two new tables to join on :) For example, SUB_ASSOC (answer_id, sub_id) and FORM_ASSOC (answer_id, sub_id). Then you can do two LEFT JOINs on these tables, and have NULLS returned if nothing exist (without populating the database with annoying nulls :) I have NOT NULL ocd lol)

Comment: I added a field by mistake to my primary key and it didn't let me change it to accept null. The ALTER query silentry leaves the FIELD to NOT NULL instead of throwing an error "you can't have nullable part of primary key".

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 non-nullable columns with the default value of null. This shouldn't be allowed by your database engine. If it is, it is rather far from a best practice.

Comment: @Abe, I added some additional information to my answer about the Non nullable column with 'NULL' default.

Answer (score 1):

sub_id is listed as a primary key

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) (5.7, but other versions say the same thing):

> A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined
>   as NOT NULL. If they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL
>   declares them so implicitly (and silently).

As to the discussion about the Non-null columns having a Default of `NULL`...

The `NULL` value in the `Default` column means that there is no default, not that the default is `NULL`.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c718d/1

If I create a simple table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE name_num(
  Number INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  Name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

And then do `desc name_num`, I get:

```
|  FIELD |    TYPE | NULL | KEY | DEFAULT | EXTRA |
---------------------------------------------------
| Number | int(11) |   NO | PRI |  (null) |       |
|   Name |    text |   NO |     |  (null) |       |
```

Again, from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> If the column cannot take NULL as the value, MySQL defines the column with no explicit DEFAULT clause. Exception: If the column is defined as part of a PRIMARY KEY but not explicitly as NOT NULL, MySQL creates it as a NOT NULL column (because PRIMARY KEY columns must be NOT NULL), but also assigns it a DEFAULT clause using the implicit default value. To prevent this, include an explicit NOT NULL in the definition of any PRIMARY KEY column.

Comment: form_id is not nullable (Null NO) but it has a default of NULL.